Why updating variables work differently in Python
I have a confusion regarding how updating variables works in Python. In the code below:
x = 1.5
y = x
y += 1
print(f"x = {x}, y = {y}")

It prints x = 1.5, y = 2.5 as expected. But when I use lists instead of numbers:
x = [1,2.5]
y = x
y += [-3]
print(f"x = {x}, y = {y}")

It is printing x = [1, 2.5, -3], y = [1, 2.5, -3], which seems counterintuitive. Why does updating a variable work differently for lists and numbers? Why is it changing the value of x? What will happen with Python objects?
